# Understing URL routing in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to create a very basic MVC framework to better understand the pattern.

I am having trouble understanding the URL routing part.
So far i've understood that the url carries 3 basic pieces of information in this format:
www.site.com/controller/method/querystring

So given the following URL:

```
www.site.com/user/delete/john

'user' is the controller
'delete' is the method of said controller
'john' is the query string
```

In my framework, i have it so if a controller is not specified in the URL, it defaults to 'index'.
If a method if not specified in the URL, it defaults to 'show'(which just outputs the html).

this way i can go to www.site.com and since it doesn't have a controller or method in the url, the
controller becomes 'index' and method 'show', thus just loading the index view.

But what if i don't want to provide a method in the url, but just www.site.com/controller/querystring
like so:
www.site.com/user/john

This would ideally load the profile for John.
But, the framework thinks 'john' in the url is the method to invoke, and not the query string.

What is the standard, a practical way to distinguish between the two?

ps:

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

echoing $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] in to http://site/profile/john gives 'profile/john'/

Comment: there is no such thing as a standard. once you structure a URL this way www.site.com/controller/method/querystring, you start enforcing rules on developers

Comment: what would be other ways to structure a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My controllers usually locate a handler method searching from more to less specific. If a method is found, it's called with the "tail" of parameters passed to it. For example, if `user/delete/john` is given, it attempts to call, in order:

```
 action_user_delete_john()
 action_user_delete('john')
 action_user('delete/john')
 generic_fallback_method('user/delete/john')
```

In your case, i'd define a set of `user_<operation>` methods (`action_user_delete`, `action_user_edit` etc) and a default `action_user` method which will be called when no `operation` param is provided and should handle urls like `user/john`

I find this technique quite flexible and powerful, but there's no standard, and you're free to invent your own.

Comment: What i ended up doing was, after i broke url into pieces (site.com/a/b/c/d)...'a', first array element is always the controller. then i look at 'b' and see if its a method of 'a'. if not, then its an argument that gets passed to a when instantiated. so the url in this example i just used, what would happen is $a->b>(array('c','d')...if 'b' wasn't a method of 'a', what would happen is $class = new $a(array('b','c','d')